# Codeigniter Pagination having page number in the middle of url

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, uri

I'm trying to use pagination class in codeigniter and my url looks something like this:

```
blah.com/posts/browse/page/1/item_per_page/10
```

is there anyway to keep the page number in the middle of url?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
            $page = null;
            $item_per_page = null;
            if (count($uri))
            {
                    foreach ($uri as $key => $value)
                    {
                            $$key = $value;
                    }
            }
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('posts/browse/page//item_per_page/1');
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            $config['per_page'] = '1';
```

Comment: Post your relevant code here.

Comment: Have you read the docs, its clearly explained there.

Comment: yes, it appears that if I wish to have page number in the middle of url, I have to use prefix/suffix parameter before initialize the pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging through code of Pagination class, I found a way to do this, but it wasn't mentioned anywhere in the tutorial.

```
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('posts/browse');
            $config['prefix'] = '/page/';
            $config['suffix'] = '/item_per_page/1';
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

this can generate urls with page number in the middle of the url.

```
eg. http://www.blah.com/posts/browse/page/2/item_per_page/1;
```

Comment: @JonathanChow thank you very much. Great solution. They has to add this in their documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html) clearly explains how to do this.

Short version: use `$config['uri_segment'] = 4;` in your pagination config. `uri_segment` tells the pagination class which uri segment contains the page #.

Comment: I've tried that, it returns blah.com/2 in the pagination urls