# CodeIgniter Pagination with number in the middle of the query string

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, query-string

I searched the whole day for any solution but did not found any.
I have the same problem as this guy here: [Codeigniter Pagination having page number in the middle of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447709/codeigniter-pagination-having-page-number-in-the-middle-of-url) but the "uri_segment" param doesn't work.

My Urls look like:
localhost/controller/0/some/filter/here/

The Pagination returns teh correct link for the next and 2. page.
But once I go there, I get a wrong link back to the first site.

I did something like this:

```
/*Paginartion Config*/
                $pagconfig['base_url']          = base_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/0/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/'.$this->uri->segment(4).'/'.$this->uri->segment(5).'/'.$this->uri->segment(6).'/'.$this->uri->segment(7).'/'.$this->uri->segment(8));
                $pagconfig['total_rows']        = $ress->num_rows;
                $pagconfig['per_page']          = 10;
                $pagconfig['uri_segment']       = 2;
                $pagconfig['prefix']            = '/'.$this->uri->segment(1).'/';
                $pagconfig['suffix']            = '/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/'.$this->uri->segment(4).'/'.$this->uri->segment(5).'/'.$this->uri->segment(6).'/'.$this->uri->segment(7).'/'.$this->uri->segment(8);
```

Also I just tried using the current_url() as base_url config param and of course I also just tried to use uri_segment = 2 without using pre- and sufix.
It never worked properly.

Routes look like this:

```
$route['map/(:num)/(:any)']                     = 'map/index/$1/$2';
$route['map/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)']              = 'map/index/$1/$2/$3';
$route['map/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']       = 'map/index/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['karte/(:num)/(:any)']                   = 'map/index/$1/$2';
$route['karte/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)']            = 'map/index/$1/$2/$3';
$route['karte/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']     = 'map/index/$1/$2/$3/$4';
```

As you can see I use two kind of routes, translates for google.
The routes and Controller also work!
If I type in by hand I get the correct paginated site content:
For Example: **localhost/controller/10/some/filter/here** returns every row beginning with 11 (it skips first 10 as it should).

Very important is that the number always appears even on the first page where it is 0 - as you can see above.

It would be so great to get any help in that one...

Best Regards